# Spring security - BeanFactory not initialized or already closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application is working fine, but when i try to add spring security user authentication, i get this error ON APPLICATION LOAD and no url's respond. I've tried all the responses and comments of this error (on this site and google), but nothing seemed to work, i can't figure it out, because i'm new to Spring. I really need this fixed. Thank you.

**relevant jar's I have in lib :**

- spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE
- spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE
- spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE
- spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE
- spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE

**Stack from eclipse :**

```
Feb 14, 2014 12:36:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Note that the irrelevant code is not present.**

**web.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/myapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <filter>  
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
        </filter>  

        <filter-mapping>  
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
        </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**myapp-servlet.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
        <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.action"
            default-target-url="/documents"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginError"
        />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="abc" password="abc" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

**EDIT 1 :**
Full trace in pastebin : http://pastebin.com/RDj1Ft1d

Comment: What else do you get in your stack trace? Paste the full log.

Comment: put the full log in pastebin.com if too big